# option value from drop down list in classic asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

Need help

I have following code with classic asp

```
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
</select>
```

Now i want just "NJ" not "New Jersey" while entering in database but it is storing "New Jersey".

on submit button in postback i am trying to read value using

```
if gAspClassUtil.isSubmitted("submit") then
     Selectedstate = Request.form("state")
end if
```

but at this time value in "Selectedstate" is "New Jersey" not "NJ"

Please suggest me how to read option "VALUE" not "TEXT" from dropdown list
in classic asp.

Comment: More code, please. If your dropdown looks as expected, and the code is what you say, it would not be possible to get the value "New Jersey" from the form data. The web page would simply not send that value to the server at all, only "NJ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are saying simply doesn't happen.

If you have a `value` attribute in an `option` tag, the value will be sent in the form data, not the text.

The `Request.Form` collection only contains the data that is posted to the server. Only the value (if present) is sent to the server, the text from the option is not even possiple to get from the form data.

Some things to check:

- Whether the `select` element is actually inside the `form` element that is posted.
- That there is no Javascript that is changing the form data when the form is submitted (e.g. getting the text from the selected option and putting in a hidden field in the form).
- That the HTML code actually looks like that to the browser. (Use View Source.)
- That the code that you are showing is actually the code that runs.

Answer (score -1):

In asp.net the dropdown list is run on server
but a  tag is a html tag and is not run in server. So there is no postback situation.
 so either you can use onchange attribute in html tag or use a submit button where you can request after submit.